Empty message content while mailing through enough_mail package in dart
I am working on a mail_client backend in pure Dart without Flutter. This is my function for sending mails in lib/send_mail.dart,
Future<void> sendMail(String name, String userName, String password, String smtpHost, int smtpPort, bool isSmtpSecure, String message, List<Recipient> recipients, String subject, String from) async {
.
.
    final builder = MessageBuilder.prepareMultipartAlternativeMessage(
      plainText: message,
    )
    final mimeMessage = builder.buildMimeMessage();
    final sendResponse = await client.sendMessage(mimeMessage);
.
.
}

And I am calling this function from bin/mail_client_backend.dart
When I run this code, the mail is sent but the content is empty.
When I directly called the function by hardcoding all the inputs of the function i.e. username, password etc. It was working fine. But, now, even if I hardcode the message variable, it's not working. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Are you sure it's empty? You are creating a multipart but only populating its text/plain part; so you probably have an empty HTML part. If your email client is set up to prefer the HTML version, that's what you will see; but the container message is not empty.

Perhaps you should understand what multipart/alternative is for. You need to generate a view for HTML viewers and an equivalent view for text/plain viewers. Way too many outfits send an empty or useless text/plain part and only really want to support HTML (often they probably feel forced to supply a text/plain part by some spam filters; but filling it with junk is a worse crime than omitting it).

Ok, got your point. Maybe at the moment, I don't require multipart message. So, I have found a simpleText method on MessageBuilder, it's more useful for me right now. Thank you for answering the question
